# The purpose of function `runZoned` of 'dart:async'

Tags: dart, dart-async

There is a special function `runZoned` provided by `dart:async`. The document is here: https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_async.html#runZoned

I'm not sure what's the purpose of this function, when will we need it, and how to use it properly?

Comment: This feature was added to compensate the lack of other useful features. It only useful if you need (want?) catch error in the code that you cannot modify. That is, it useful if you want work with code that throw unexptected exception in asynchronous operations. The `runZoned` can trapping these unobserved exceptions that you cannot catch by some reason due the errors in that source code. As for me, it is better not use code that throw unobserved exceptions than run this code with known bugs in `runZoned` environment. Lack of other useful features: async/await

Comment: When compiler support `async / await` operations it (or other tool) can detect potential mistakes in source code with asynchronous operations. In this case it can generate the warnings for programmers. In this case `runZoned` not so often needed if program written with the conventions of `async/await` operations programming and do not contains obvious potential mistakes that can lead to unobserved exceptions. In fact, `runZoned` are `forced` trap for missed (unobserved) exeptions in asynchronous code, which are physically impossible to catch due to improperly written source code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look at this code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  fineMethod().catchError((s) {}, test : (e) => e is String);
  badMethod().catchError((s) {}, test : (e) => e is String);
}

Future fineMethod() {
  return new Future(() => throw "I am fine");
}

Future badMethod() {
  new Future(() => throw "I am bad");
  return new Future(() => throw "I am fine");
}
```

Output

```
Unhandled exception:
I am bad
```

Now look at this code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  fineMethod().catchError((s) {}, test : (e) => e is String);

  runZoned(() {
    badMethod().catchError((s) {}, test : (e) => e is String);
  }, onError : (s) {
    print("It's not so bad but good in this also not so big.");
    print("Problem still exists: $s");
  });
}

Future fineMethod() {
  return new Future(() => throw "I am fine");
}

Future badMethod() {
  new Future(() => throw "I am bad");
  return new Future(() => throw "I am fine");
}
```

Output

```
It's not so bad but good in this also not so big.
Problem still exists: I am bad
```

You should strictly avoid using `badMethod` if this possible.

Only if this not possible you may temporary use `runZoned`

Also you may use `runZoned` to simulate `sandboxed` execution of tasks.

**Updated version of the answer:**

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> main() async {
  try {
    await fineMethod();
  } catch (e) {
    log(e);
  }

  await runZonedGuarded(() async {
    try {
      await badMethod();
    } catch (e) {
      log(e);
    }
  }, (e, s) {
    print("========");
    print("Unhandled exception, handled by `runZonedGuarded`");
    print("$e");
    print("========");
  });
}

Future badMethod() {
  // Unhandled exceptions
  Future(() => throw "Bad method: bad1");
  Future(() => throw "Bad method: bad2");
  return Future(() => throw "Bad method: fine");
}

Future fineMethod() {
  return Future(() => throw "Fine method: fine");
}

void log(e) {
  print('Handled exception:');
  print('$e');
}
```

Output:

```
Handled exception:
Fine method: fine
========
Unhandled exception, handled by `runZonedGuarded`
Bad method: bad1
========
========
Unhandled exception, handled by `runZonedGuarded`
Bad method: bad2
========
Handled exception:
Bad method: fine
```