# Flutter: TextField onChanged handler silently swallows exceptions

Tags: flutter

When an exception is thrown and unhandled in a `TextField.onChanged` handler it doesn't bubble up to the global `Flutter.onError` handler so it's silently missed. Is there a way to globally handle these errors so that I'm at least aware that they're thrown when developing?

It appears to be caught and converted into an object in `MethodChannel._handleAsMethodCall()`, but I don't understand how it's handled from there.

```dart
main() {
  runApp(Test());
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Input",
            ),
            onChanged: (input) {
              throw Exception(); // <-------- swallowed by framework
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have to call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` before you can assign your custom error handler - the following code works for me:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // <- this needs to happen before assigning your error handler
  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) => print('custom error handling');
  runApp(Test());
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Input",
            ),
            onChanged: (input) {
              print(input);
              throw Exception(); 
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The console output when writing 'uiae':

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Chrome...
Restarted application in 434ms.
u
custom error handling
ui
custom error handling
uia
custom error handling
uiae
custom error handling
```

You may also want to take a look at [Flutter: How to implement FlutterError.OnError correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54294656/flutter-how-to-implement-fluttererror-onerror-correctly) and [Flutter catching all unhandled exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879455/flutter-catching-all-unhandled-exceptions) as they seem to be related to your problem.